# Draw Text under some angle with specific font

Tags: scichart

I am trying to draw text inside columns of bar chart. In order to do that I am using **DrawText** of **IRenderContext2D**. But it does not allow me to specify angle under which text need to be rendered and also does not allow to specify font.
I can't use annotations as they are WPF elements and will slow down my chart (I will have text for each column).
Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid as of v4.0, without changing the code base, there is no way to specify an angle when using [IRenderContext2D.DrawText](http://www.scichart.com/documentation/v4.x/webframe.html#SciChart.Drawing~SciChart.Drawing.Common.IRenderContext2D~DrawText.html) in SciChart